# Is there a grammar (not necessarily context-free) that generates $n^2$ zeroes?

Tags: formal-languages

My Introduction to Computation Theory professor talked about how we can write more general grammars (called unrestricted grammars) for languages that are not context-free. For example, the language: $\{0^{2^n} : n\geq0\}$ is not context-free, so it cannot be generated by a context-free grammar.

I am wondering if the language: $\{0^{n^2} : n\ge0\}$ is also not context-free, and what could be the grammar for it?

For this language, we would have to generate $n^2$ zeroes, which seems awkward and difficult to put into grammar form.

Comment: Have you seen: [context free grammar with words of length $n^2$ or $n^3$](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/60023/does-there-exist-context-free-grammar-with-words-of-length-n2-or-n3)

Comment: Here is [$2^n$ case](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/76310/context-sensitive-grammar-for-a2n-mid-n-geq-0), [$a^{n^2}$](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/71567/unrestricted-grammar-to-generate-an2). A little search does magic.

Comment: @Community Please change the "This question already has an answer here" into the second suggestion cited by Evil: https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/71567/4287 The question is not whether the language is context-free, but how it has a grammar "Is there a grammar (not necessarily context-free) that generates n^2 zeroes?"

Comment: @HendrikJan The question is both of those things. One of them is an exact duplicate and the other is the reason we shouldn't have two separate questions bundled into one.